# Capturar click em document para fechar menu que estiver aberto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou implementando uma função em meu menu onde o mesmo fechara o conteúdo do `dropdown` que estiver aberto SE o clique for em qualquer outro lugar exceto no menu em si.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
   var $menuOpened = $('.dropdown-content');
   $.each($menuOpened, function(index, value) {
      if ($(value).hasClass('show') && event.target != $(value)) {
         // Fecha o menu
      }
   });
 });
```

Só que sempre `true` quando clico em qualquer outro lugar, até mesmo no botão responsavel por abrir o `dropdown` em questão, logo, ele nunca é exibido para poder ser fechado.

> Possuo mais de 1 dropdown que pode ser aberto no mesmo menu.

Comment: Devo ter precebido mal, já retirei a resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode verificar se o target é o seu botão e ignorar a ação seguinte:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {

   if ($(event.target).attr('class').indexOf('classe_botoes') > -1) return; // verifica se o alvo esta sendo o botão

   var $menuOpened = $('.dropdown-content');
   $.each($menuOpened, function(index, value) {
      if ($(value).hasClass('show') && event.target != $(value)) {
         // Fecha o menu
      }
   });
 });
```

`indexOf` é uma função javascript que verifica se contém um certo valor em um array, se ele encontrar ele retorna o índice, se não encontrar é retornado *-1*. Visto que string é array de chars em javascript, o `if` verifica se dentre as classes do elemento na tela que foi clicado existe alguma com *classe_botoes*, por esse motivo a verificação é se for `> -1` que é encontrado.

Comment: os elementos não possuem id.

Comment: De alguma forma você terá que identificar àquele botão, se puder colocá-lo um `id` além de ser a forma mais correta é a mais fácil. Mas pode usar outro seletor, como `class` por exemplo.

Comment: Tenho mais de 1 menu que pode ser aberto, por isso o motivo do loop e do não uso de ID

Comment: funcionou! você pode explicar um pouco mais o primeiro `if` ?

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer essa validação através do `target` do evento.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
   if (event.target.id == 'btnAbrirMenu' || event.target.id == 'div_do_menu')
      alert("clicou no menu ou no botão de abrir o menu");
   else
      alert("clicou fora do menu");
 });
```

No fim das contas fica algo como:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
   if (event.target.id == 'btnAbrirMenu' || event.target.id == 'div_do_menu')
      return;
   else { 
      //fechar menu;
   }
 });
```